# ExceptionInInitializerError when using WordNet

Tags: java, wordnet

I recently decided to download JWNL for a Java interface to WordNet. Following various tutorials (like http://jwordnet.sourceforge.net/handbook.html), I downloaded WordNet (2.1), and then JWNL, setting the dictionary_path line in file_properties.xml to the path to WordNet.

```
<param name="dictionary_path" value="c:/res/wordnet/2.1/dict"/>
```

I added all the jars to my classpath, and, in Eclipse, I created the following simple class for testing:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
                                             JWNLException {
          JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("C:\\path\\file_properties.xml"));
          Dictionary wordnet = Dictionary.getInstance();

          IndexWord word = wordnet.getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, "monarch");
          for(Synset syn : word.getSenses()) {
               System.out.println(syn.getGloss());
          }
    }
```

Running in Eclipse produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at net.didion.jwnl.util.factory.Element.install(Element.java:31)
at net.didion.jwnl.JWNL.initialize(JWNL.java:169)
at TestingOnWordNet.main(TestingOnWordNet.java:28)

Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
at net.didion.jwnl.util.MessageLog.<init>(MessageLog.java:11)
at net.didion.jwnl.dictionary.Dictionary.<clinit>(Dictionary.java:24)
... 5 more

Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
... 10 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
... 11 more
```

Is there something I'm missing? I'm preparing to look at an alternative like JAWS, but I was hoping there might be a way to remedy the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this post, I would strongly recommend switching from JWNL to JAWS: http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html, if for no other reason than that a call to
`System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir","C:/res/wordnet/2.1/dict/");`
is simpler and easier to understand than the file_properties.xml file.

Comment: I too switched to JAWS. JWPL has complicated APIs. :P

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add jars to classpath.
Add lib/commons-logging.jar to classpath.